# Excel fiscal quarter formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I write formula to drive Fiscal quarter from Date

My  2016 fiscal year starts from Feb 2015 and ends in Jan 2016

So for Feb 2015 the desired out put is Q1-16 and for Jan 2016 is Q4-16

Answer (score 2):

You could use a formula like this (based on the date being in cell A1):

```
="Q" & INT(MOD(MONTH(A1)+10,12)/3)+1 & "-" & RIGHT(YEAR(A1)+(MONTH(A1)>1),2)
```

This uses `&` to concatenate the pieces.

Calculating the quarter uses the MOD function to shift the months and bump January to the end (the MOD function gives you the remainder after you divide the expression `MONTH(A1)+10` by 12).  Dividing the result by `3` and taking the integer, then adding `1`, converts that to quarter.

The formula uses Boolean math to adjust the year if the month isn't January (if `MONTH(A1)>1` is true, Excel treats the expression as the value `1`, otherwise it's treated as `0`).

Comment: You can shorten the `Q` part a little, to `=INT(MOD(MONTH(A1)+10,12)/3)+1`.

Comment: @Scott: Very good.  I was looking for something like that and it was too far past my bedtime to figure it out.  I'll incorporate that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Build a lookup table like so :

[image]

The full formula would be :

```
="Q" & VLOOKUP(MONTH(E2),A:B,2,0) & "-" & TEXT(E2,"YY")+VLOOKUP(MONTH(E2),A:C,3,0)
```

I guess the formula and having to build a lookup table is more overhead, but I usually do it this way because :

- Other formulas can reuse this table
- Changes in business logic would can easily be made by changing the lookup table, the formula(s) will not need to be changed
- Visually easier to understand, especially if the Excel sheet is used by other people

Comment: I normally use TEXT(<cell>,"YY") to get the last two digits of the year, instead of RIGHT(YEAR(<cell>),2)

Comment: Look at what happens if you enter a date before 01-Feb-2009.  Then change the last part of your formula to `TEXT(E2+VLOOKUP(MONTH(E2),A:C,3,0),"YY")`.  (It's the exact same characters as in your answer, but rearranged.)